# React Toggle ID

Tags: javascript, reactjs, toggle

I have an issue with a toggling div. It is probably a small thing, but I can not find the reason why it works the first time I click on it (and the panel expands), but when clicking again it does not close. Maybe someone can see why the second time I click on the item, the id is not being send along with the element "e"? Thanks a lot!

```
class FlexPanel extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      toggle1: false,
      toggle2: false,
      toggle3: false,
    };
  }
  render() {
    const toggleOpen = (e) => {
      const id = e.target.id;
      const toggleId = `toggle${id}`;
      let toggleItem = this.state[toggleId];
      this.setState({
        [toggleId]: !toggleItem,
      });
    };

    const { toggle1, toggle2, toggle3 } = this.state;
    console.log(toggle1);
    return (
      <div className="panels">
        <div
          id={1}
          className={`panel panel1 ${toggle1 ? "open open-active" : "closed"} `}
          onClick={(e) => {
            toggleOpen(e);
          }}
        >
          <p>Consultes</p>
          <p>Teràpies</p>
          <p>Recolzament</p>
        </div>
        <div
          id={2}
          className={`panel panel2 ${toggle2 ? "open open-active" : "closed"} `}
          onClick={(e) => {
            toggleOpen(e);
          }}
        >
          <p>Videoconsultes</p>
          <p>en grup</p>
          <p>i individuals</p>
        </div>
        <div
          id={3}
          className={`panel panel3 ${toggle3 ? "open open-active" : "closed"} `}
          onClick={(e) => {
            toggleOpen(e);
          }}
        >
          <p>Jordi</p>
          <p>Arjó</p>
          <p>Teràpies</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default FlexPanel;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `toggleOpen()` you need to change `const id = e.target.id;` to `const id = e.currentTarget.id`

Check out the modified code here

[image: Edit awesome-jennings-pl2yw]

More about difference between `e.target` and `e.currentTarget` [in the official documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)

Comment: @CarlosdelRíoFrancés No problem. I've updated the answer with link.
You can try to `console.log` you `e` or `e.target` or `e.currentTarget` to see what you actually hit

Answer (score 0):

You need to use updater function for `setState`

```js
this.setState((prevSate) => {
        let toggleItem = prevState[toggleId];
        return {
          [toggleId]: !toggleItem,
        }
      });
```